# Java when shifting bits left, overflows dont disappear but appear back on other side

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

```
int i = 0x000000FF;
i = i << 24;

message = String.format("0x%08X", i);
// prints the message 0xFF000000

int i = 0x000000FF;
i = i << 32;

message = String.format("0x%08X", i);
// prints the message 0x000000FF
```

I was expecting the second one to print 0x00000000

What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Java Language Specification [15.19. Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is `int`, then only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator `&` ([§15.22.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1)) with the mask value `0x1f` (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range `0` to `31`, inclusive.

So, `i << 32` is the same as `i << 0`, i.e. no shift at all.

Comment: Ah yes, I discovered this one the hard way myself a few months ago.